# Residence Card for UK process

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa, residence-cards

I want to ask for a Residence card. I have a 6 month EEA Family Permit.  I have some doubts:

1. Do I have to open a UK bank account? I have a EU bank account.
2. Do I have to ask for a NIN (National Insurance Number)?
3. What other things should I do? What other documents are required other than the ones I used for the EEA Family Permit?

Thank you!

Comment: Knowing your nationaility would be useful.

Comment: Hi!! Colombian.